# Retrieve a list of strings from one key vault secret

Tags: c#, .net, azure-keyvault

I need to use the Options pattern to populate this class from the key vault

```
public class TestOptions
{
    public string Continent {get; set; }
    public List<string> Countries{ get; set; }
}
```

In the key vault I have the following secrets

```
Test--Continent 
Test--Countries
```

The TestOptions class is loaded by the following code

```
builder.Register(ctx => ctx.Resolve<IConfiguration>().GetSection("Test").Get<TestOptions>()).SingleInstance();
```

The Continent property is populated properly.
The Countries property is null and I suspect it is a problem with secret value. How should be this value?

When I had this value in the appsettings and it was working perfect:

```
"Test": {
    "Continent": "Europe",
    "Countries": [
      "Germany",
      "France",
      "Spain"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You could also implement an `IConfigureOptions<T>` service to translate one form of configuration to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store a list of strings in a single key vault secret and retrieve it in a `List<string>` property in your `TestOptions` class, you need to serialize and deserialize the list into a format that can be stored as a string. JSON would be the choice for this purpose.

*store the JSON-serialized list as a single string in your Azure Key Vault secret*

Example in Azure Key Vault:

```
Test--Continent: "Europe"
Test--Countries: ["Germany", "France", "Spain"]
```

Now Modify registration code :

```
builder.Register(ctx =>
{
    var configuration = ctx.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
    var testOptions = new TestOptions
    {
        Continent = configuration["Test--Continent"],
        Countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(configuration["Test--Countries"])
    };
    return testOptions;
}).SingleInstance();
```

The `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(configuration["Test--Countries"])` is used to deserialize the JSON string into a `List<string>`. To Ensure that the JSON structure in the key vault secret matches the expected format for deserialization.

Hope this helpps you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to use indexes in the Key Vault secret names, like so:

```
Test--Countries--0
Test--Countries--1
Test--Countries--2
```

In this scenario, Test--Countries--0 would have "Germany" for the value, Test--Countries--1 would have "France" for the value, and Test--Countries--2 would have "Spain" for the value.

See the following from Microsoft, showing examples of how to bind arrays to classes via Key Vault:

[Microsoft Key Vault - Bind an Array to a Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bind-an-array-to-a-class)